# How to fix `can't evaluate field extraHosts in type interface {}` in _helpers.tpl in helm

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, templating, gluu

I am trying to get some values from Umbrella chart in helm in `_helpers.tpl` but I for some reason I am getting the error `executing "gluu.ldaplist" at <.Values.ldap.extraHo...>: can't evaluate field extraHosts in type interface {}`

This is what I am trying to do.
`_helpers.ptl`

```
{{- define "gluu.ldaplist" -}}
{{- $hosts := .Values.ldap.extraHosts -}}
{{- $genLdap := dict "host" (printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name .Values.ldapType) "port" .Values.ldapPort -}}
{{- $hosts := prepend $hosts $genLdap -}}
{{- $local := dict "first" true -}}
{{- range $k, $v := $hosts -}}
{{- if not $local.first -}},{{- end -}}{{- printf "%s:%.f" $v.host $v.port -}}{{- $_ := set $local "first" false -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

And this is part of `values.yml` for the umbrella chart
`values.yml`

```
ldap:
  enabled: true
  type: opendj
  extraHosts: [
    host: opendj,
    port: 3434
  ] #array of k,v e.g host: host1, port: port1
```

Directory structure

```
helm/
  charts/
     chart_a/
       templates/
          configMap.yml ----->>> this is where I want to use it
  templates/
     _helpers.tpl ---->>>> where the failing function is
  requirements.yml
  values.yml ---------->>> where the ldap values are
```

The `configMap.yml` looks like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "oxauth.fullname" . }}-cm
data:
  GLUU_CONFIG_ADAPTER: {{ .Values.global.configAdapterName | quote }}
  GLUU_LDAP_URL: {{ template "gluu.ldaplist" . }}
```

NOTE: The `_helpers.tpl` is under the main/umbrella chart. `chart_a` is a subchart.

Expected results are something like `GLUU_LDAP_URL:"opendj:3434"`

Helm version:

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.10.0", GitCommit:"9ad53aac42165a5fadc6c87be0dea6b115f93090", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.10.0", GitCommit:"9ad53aac42165a5fadc6c87be0dea6b115f93090", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Expected result is that the function `{{- define "gluu.ldaplist" -}}` in `_helpers.tpl` completes without error even if no values are provided in the array. 
If there are values provided, the expected string is `host:port` as output.

If this can be done in another way, I welcome any suggestion.

Comment: The “host: opendj” and “port: 3434” aren’t paired together in your YAML. If you want to use [ ... ] for the array, wrap the host/port pair in { ... }. Alternatively drop the square brackets and use a - indicating a new array item for each host/port pair.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. When I put `extraHosts` outside of ldap, it gets called fine.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a complete minimal example. What is your directory structure, what command are you running, what version of Helm, and what your expected output is. That way people can try to reproduce locally.

Comment: I have updated the description. @AmitKumarGupta

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough info for me to try to reproduce. First off, are you saying `templates`, `requirements.yml`, and `values.yml` are sibling to you `charts` directory, rather than inside your `chart_b` directory? Also, what command are you running? Could you provide a complete minimal example that works? That might entail creating a dummy non-`_xxx.tpl` file so that `helm template` isn't a no-op. You could show the desired output you'd expect from running `helm template` (if that is indeed the command you're running, I don't know) just as you've shown the input `values.yml`.

Comment: I've set up a directory in Helm chart structure with some subdirectories and files matching what you've provided, plus some extra files to make it not no-op, and run `helm template . --values values.yml` and am not seeing the error you're doing.  But I have no idea if what I'm doing is similar at all to what you're doing.

Comment: can you provide deployment/service yaml where you want your rendered values to be

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta question updated

Comment: Thanks, this can be solved with global values. Will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with global values which allow values in the parent chart to override (or supply unspecified) values in the child subcharts.

From the [Helm docs on *Subcharts and Global Values*](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#subcharts-and-global-values):

> 1. A subchart is considered “stand-alone”, which means a subchart can never explicitly depend on its parent chart.
> 2. For that reason, **a subchart cannot access the values of its parent**.
> 3. A parent chart can override values for subcharts.
> 4. **Helm has a concept of *global values* that can be accessed by all charts**.

(At first I didn't think to search for "helm subchart" but once I did an Internet search for that term, this was the first or second result)

Here's a minimal example that solves your issue:

#### Directory Structure

```
helm
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
│   └── chart_a
│       ├── Chart.yaml
│       └── templates
│           └── configMap.yml
├── templates
│   └── _helpers.tpl
└── values.yaml
```

Note: I added `Chart.yaml` files to make it actually work, renamed `values.yml` to `values.yaml` so that it works by default without extra flags, and removed `requirements.yml` since it wasn't necessary to reproduce the problem and solution.

#### `values.yaml`

```
global:
  ldap:
    enabled: true
    type: opendj
    extraHosts:
    - host: opendj
      port: 3434
  ldapType: xxx
  ldapPort: 123
```

The key was to nest what you had under a special `global` key. Note, I also added `ldapType` and `ldapPort` since they were in your `_helpers.tpl`, and I fixed the YAML structure you had under `extraHosts`. What was there before didn't actually represent a list of maps with `host` and `port` keys. Without this fix, the `helm` command doesn't fail but doesn't output what you want either.

#### Result

```
$ helm template .
---
# Source: helm/charts/chart_a/templates/configMap.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm
data:
  GLUU_LDAP_URL: release-name-xxx:123,opendj:3434
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing please. I am struggling referencing for example `serviceName` of `chart_a` in parent chart. Could you kindly help on that. I have an ingress that I want to deploy in parent chart but the `service` to referenced by the ingress is in `chart_a`

Comment: Glad that worked! As for your new question, it would be best to create a new question on StackOverflow.